# How to pick some files in a commit using Git

Tags: git, cherry-pick

In one of the commits that I want to `cherry-pick` from Branch B to Branch A, there are four files that changed, but I only want one of the files in that commit to be on Branch A. How do I get that file on Branch A?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little bit of a hassle but this works:

If you have more files you don't want to commit then files you want to commit:

`git checkout BranchA

git cherry-pick <sha1>

git reset HEAD^

git add <file>

git commit

git reset --hard`

If you have more files to commit then not:

`git checkout BranchA

git cherry-pick --no-commit <sha1>

git reset HEAD <file>

git commit`

Answer (score 1):

One option would be `git show -p COMMIT_HASH:path/to/file > path/to/file` to grab the file which has changed and then add and commit.

Answer (score 0):

cherry-pick, revert all files but the one you want, commit amend:

```
git cherry-pick BranchB
git show --pretty=format: --name-only | grep . | grep -v fileyouwant | xargs git checkout HEAD^ -- 
git commit -a --amend -C HEAD
```